# Representation of Long Double value

Tags: c, printf, floating-point-precision

I want to know how a value is represnted in long double.
Is it as L or LF . Im asking this since in  some places i have read it is L and in some LF.
In one of the exam answers and in some websites like indiabix it was L and in some stack overflow posts its LF.

Comment: I suspect this question is about suffixes for constants in C or C++ (which?), could you clarify?

Comment: Are we talking about `printf`/`scanf` placeholders or constant suffixes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *floating-suffix*: one of
>
> ```
>    f l F L
> ```

(C99 §6.4.4.2 ¶1)

> An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. If suffixed by the letter `f` or `F`, it has
>   type `float`. If suffixed by the letter `l` or `L`, it has type `long double`.

(ibidem, ¶4)

Answer (score 0):

Use "%f" for both float and double, it is converted to double regardless.

The long double data type can have these conversion specifiers %Le,%LE,%Lf,%LG,%Lg,

Comment: 1) `L` can be applied to `a, A, e, E, f, F, g, G` 2) This answer applies to `printf()` family of functions.  Differences exist for `scanf()`

Answer (score -1):

Extract from ["C how to program", Deitel, 7th edition](http://www.deitel.com/Books/C/CHowtoProgram7e/tabid/3635/Default.aspx), p168:

> Data type:long double ,printf conversion specifier:%Lf ,scanf
>   conversion specifier:%Lf
>
> Data type:double ,printf conversion specifier:%f ,scanf conversion
>   specifier:%lf

So in both cases your answer is `%Lf`.